# Group by complex database set

Tags: c#, linq

I have my `User` object that will bring the user data questions that he answered

I need to show the user and count which was the type of question he answered most. Let's say he answered 3 valid questions of type A, 1 of type B and 4 of type C. Then i would need to show his data, 4 and C.

This is my `Result` class

```
public class Result
{
    public int ResultID { get; set; }
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public int questionID { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int valid { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `User` class

```
public class User
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to group or filter? You talk about grouping, but then your sample code is filtering... and it's trying to use a property (`Resultados`) which doesn't exist.

Comment: what is "Resultados" ? It is not available in your code

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to translate some of the code, now it's right !

I need first to filter for the valid questions, which will have the value 1, and them group by the type value wich can be (A, B, C, D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `valid` must be a positive number:

```
var participantsWithBestResults = db.Participantes.Where(x => x.Results.Any(y => y.valid > 0))
.Select(x => new
{
    user = x,
    bestResult = x.Results.Where(y => y.valid > 0)
        .GroupBy(y => y.type)
        .OrderByDescending(y => y.Count())
        .Select(y => new
        {
            type = y.Key,
            count = y.Count()
        })
        .FirstOrDefault()
});
```

Comment: Yes, it will be 1 for valid. How would i now order it for the type of the result ?

Comment: So you need results, and not users?

Comment: I need to show the user and count which was the type of question he  answered most.

Let's say he answered 3 valid questions of type A, 1 of type B and 4 of type C. Then i would need to show 4 and C

Comment: Well, you should have written your question that way.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it was kind of clear. Is it possible ?

Comment: And by the way it didn't work, i still have results that have valid as 0

Comment: It filters participants that have `Any` valid result. Do you need only those participants that have only valid results?

Comment: Ohh, no. What i need is all the participants and their results but only the results that are in the rule i explained earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66664/discussion-between-dmitry-popov-and-terkhos).